# get data from hexadecimal character

Tags: c++, cocoa, rtf

I have the code as below:

```
NSString* str = @"π";
const char* chr = [str UTF8String];
```

The value for chr is "\xcf\x80" which is a sequence of hexadecimal charter.
To write as RTF file I need to extract the value excluding "\x" from this hexadecimal character.

How should I do to get the data?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In C the `char` type is an integral type so you can produce a hexadecimal representation of a character just as you would any other integer value - using the `%x` format specifier. To convert a complete C string to a string of hexadecimal just iterate over the string and build up the result. Rough code, typed directly into answer so expected errors:

```
NSString *str = ...
const char *cStr = [str UTF8String];
NSMutableString *hexStr = [NSMutableString new]; // for result
while( *cStr ) // loop while cStr is not pointing at a null char
{
   [hexStr appendFormat:@"%02x", *cStr++]; // %02x - zero fill, width 2, hex
}
```